# Почему внутри функции не видны аргументы?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");


    const double nums[6] = { 1, 2.7, 4.7, 6, 10 };

    double getMax(double* numbers, int n); 
    {
        int max = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        }
    };


}
```

Имеется такой код, почему пишет, что

> numbers: необъявленный идентификатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Функции нельзя определять внутри других функций. Так что даже если убрать лишнюю `;`, работать не будет.

Comment: О каких "аргументах" вы ведете речь? У вас в коде определена только одна функция - `main`. И у нее нет никаких "аргументов".

Answer (score 1):

```
double getMax(double* numbers, int n);
```

это просто объявление функции `getMax`. Далее идет код `main`, в котором используется не объявленная переменная `numbers`.

На всякий случай наперёд - в C/C++ вложенных функций нет (разве что гда-то как не стандартное расширение).

Comment: Только, вот, *`"...где-то как не стандартное расширение..."`* -- это на самом деле, в самом широко используемом компиляторе языка Си -- gcc -)

Comment: @avp Но как нестандартное расширение?

Comment: Если в стандарте нет, значит нестандартное. Главное, что иногда очень удобное (не зря же его люди в компилятор добавили -))